# Oculus Quest 2 Cameras not working

Tags: oculus-rift, beat-saber

Yesterday, I accidentally dropped my Quest 2, and when I put it back on, it was working perfectly fine. I played it perfectly fine this morning, with no errors. But just now, the Tracking or Cameras has stopped working. Passthrough mode just now started only showing black, and every time I put the headset on, I get a message saying that there was a tracking error and that I couldn't play any games that require tracking.

Comment: Handtracking works fine, for some reason. Settings > Device > Tracking is off, and when I turn it on, I get about 3 errors all saying that there was a tracking error.

Answer (score 0):

About 2 days later, it randomly started working again. I don't know why.